# Spring Cloud Stream + Kafka Dynamic Destination + Error handling

Tags: project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream, dynamic-binding

We have an application on Spring cloud Stream integrated with Project Reactor. We dynamically set the destination topic by setting the spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination in the Message header and publish messages.
We are looking to handle error scenarios like the kafka server being down intermittently or the topic not being available while publishing.
We have implemented @ServiceActivator to handle all errors. When the topic is set dynamically, producer errors are not being caught by the ServiceActivator and only consumer errors hit the ServiceActivator.
If we set the out.destination topic ahead, then the producer error is also caught.
Is there any way to enable errorChannel for dynamic destinations as well?
Sample code below,
application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: generate_flux;process
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9094
          required-acks: all
          producer-properties:
            retries: 2
      bindings:
        generate_flux-out-0:
          destination: source
        process-in-0:
          destination: source
          group: processors
        process-out-0:
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

In application class, Function with dynamic destination topic set,

```
@Bean
 public Function<Flux<Message<String>>, Flux<Message<String>>> process() {
     return (msg) -> {
       return msg.flatMap(
           message -> {
             log.info("individual msg " + message);
             Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
             headers.put("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "processed");
             MessageHeaders mh = new MessageHeaders(headers);
             return Mono.just(MessageBuilder.createMessage("vvvv processed ", mh));
           });
     };
 }
```

Service Activator:

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
  public void handle(final ErrorMessage em) {
    log.error("Error caught" + em.toString());
  }
```

Started the spring boot application, ensured messages are consumed and published, and then deleted the topic "processed" to create a failure scenario.

With the above,
TimeoutException is seen for Producer but not caught by Service Activator errorChannel:

```
   Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic processed not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder$ProducerConfigurationMessageHandler@f258f76]; nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic processed not present in metadata after 60000 ms., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[15], headers={id=13dc2799-45c5-0c10-2e62-4e296f62d1dc, spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination=processed, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1620856125106}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnNext
    org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$bindFunctionToDestinations$9(FunctionConfiguration.java:501)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ Flux.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$bindFunctionToDestinations$9(FunctionConfiguration.java:501)
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1041)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
        at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$null$7(FunctionConfiguration.java:512)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:196)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:487)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:420)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199)
        at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.tryEmitNext(UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.java:119)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils.lambda$null$8(IntegrationReactiveUtils.java:141)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:396)
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:455)
        at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:429)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2069)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2051)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1928)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1814)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1531)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic processed not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:574)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:389)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:517)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder$SendingHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder.lambda$null$7(FunctionConfiguration.java:512)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:196)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:487)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:420)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:387)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199)
    at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.tryEmitNext(UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.java:119)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils.lambda$null$8(IntegrationReactiveUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:396)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:455)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:429)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2069)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2051)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1988)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1814)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1178)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1075)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

But service activator displayed only consumer related errors,

```
 ERROR c.i.f.e.d.DedupeProcessorApplication - intuit_tid= Error caughtErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application-1.process-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[43], headers={kafka_offset=4, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7da2cc8f, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTopic=source, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620856185102, kafka_groupId=processors}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[43], headers={kafka_offset=4, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7da2cc8f, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTopic=source, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620856185102, kafka_groupId=processors}], headers={kafka_data=ConsumerRecord(topic = source, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 4, CreateTime = 1620856185102, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 43, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@4cb51739), id=a2fef876-a0ab-c825-9ee6-50b355044e51, sourceData=ConsumerRecord(topic = source, partition = 0, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 4, CreateTime = 1620856185102, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 43, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@4cb51739), timestamp=1620856206192}] for original GenericMessage [payload=byte[43], headers={kafka_offset=4, kafka_consumer=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@7da2cc8f, deliveryAttempt=3, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, contentType=application/json, kafka_receivedTopic=source, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1620856185102, kafka_groupId=processors}]
```

Just by altering the topic to be not dynamic, i.e removed the below line from the Funtion

```
// headers.put("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", "processed");
```

and added the destination topic to out configuration,

```
      process-out-0:
          destination: processed
          producer:
            error-channel-enabled: true
```

able to get the producer error at ServiceActivator. Log below

```
Error caughtErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.KafkaSendFailureException: nested exception is org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaProducerException: Failed to send; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for processed-0:120000 ms has passed since batch creation, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[15], headers={contentType=application/json, id=0ba150e5-8e6f-81f1-b9c4-cda115171ce0, timestamp=1620856522352}] [record=ProducerRecord(topic=processed, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=[B@339a63df, timestamp=null)], headers={id=1acaece7-c596-c9ff-440b-37df824bd564, timestamp=1620856642357}]
```

My question is how do I get hold of errors when the destination topic is dynamically set in the Message's header and not configured?

Answer (score 0):

I should probably write a blog I can reference, but the short answer is: there is nothing tat we can do on s-c-stream side to handle errors produces as a result of reactive function for one simple reason - we have absolutely no control over what's going on with the stream.

The fundamental difference between reactive and imperative function is that imperative function acts as message listener and is invoked by us (the framework) on each message. In contrast, reactive function is only invoked once during application initialization where we connect the source stream to the Publisher exposed by user function and with that we hand off complete control to the user.

So it';s a question of unit of work where in imperative function such unit is Message and with reactive such unit is the entire stream of Messages which could be infinite.

All this means that when writing reactive function you must rely on the rich error handling capabilities of reactive API itself.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your response. We went with using onErrorDropped feature of ProjectReactor, but this has a drawback of the stream breaking after a certain time and no more the messages are consumed. So, this is not yet resolved for us. Are you aware of any recent changes in Spring cloud stream kafka binder, that can enable custom handling the messages in errorChannel, where there is dynamic binding of destination topic? Thanks.